# Django - Can't get the specific primary key (id) for an object in a list of objects

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get the specific pk of the selected object when the user accepts a delivery. My problem is that I'm getting only the first object's pk in the list every time. I want to get the pk of the selected object.

views:

```
@login_required(login_url="/signin/?next=/driver/")
def deliveries_available_page(request):

    deliveries = Delivery.objects.filter(
        status_of_delivery__in=[Delivery.DELIVERY_POSTED]
    )
    
    #When driver accept delivery then status of delivery changes to delivering
    if request.method == 'POST':
        delivery = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=request.POST.get('receipt_number'))
        if delivery:
            delivery.status_of_delivery = Delivery.DELIVERY_DELIVERING
            delivery.driver = request.user.driver
            messages.success(request, 'Delivery Accepted')
            delivery.save()
    
        return redirect(reverse('driver:deliveries_available'))
    return render(request, 'driver/deliveries_available.html', {
        "GOOGLE_API_MAP": settings.GOOGLE_API_MAP,
        "del": deliveries
    })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100" style="padding-bottom: 50px">
    <div id="map"></div>
    {% if del %}
    {% for d in del %}
    <div class="card" id="delivery-popup">
        <div class="card-body p-2">
            <div class="details">
                <div class="p-2">
                    <strong id="address"></strong>
                    <div>
                        <strong id="show-info"></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong id="show-distance"></strong>
                        <strong id="show-duration"></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong id="show-price"></strong>
                        <strong id="show-id"></strong>
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"        name="accept">Accept</button>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ d.receipt_number }}" name="receipt_number">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
  
                    {% if messages %}
                    {% for m in messages %}
                    {% if m.tags %}
                    <script>alert("{{ m }}")</script>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

[image: When i click on the address the pk stays the same]

I need the specific pk so when user accept delivery, then the right delivery is accepted and removed from the map. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

I can get the specific pk by creating new url and passing it in the url but i want user to accept delivery on the map page.

script added to html

```
<script>
//Google map and using api to display deliveries on map and click event to show delivery details
function initMap() {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 53.350140, lng: -6.266155 },
        zoom: 13,
    });

    fetch("{% url 'driver:available_deliveries' %}").then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
        console.log(json);

        for (let d = 0; d < json.deliveries.length; d++) {
            const delivery = json.deliveries[d];
            const position = { lat: delivery.delivery_address_latitude, lng: delivery.delivery_address_longitude };
            const show_on_map = new google.maps.Marker
                ({
                    position,
                    map,
                });

            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<small><strong>" + delivery.address + "<medium><br>€" + delivery.price
            }).open(map, show_on_map);

            show_on_map.addListener("click", () => {
                PopUpDelivery(delivery);
            })
        }
    })
}

function PopUpDelivery(delivery) {
    $("#delivery-popup").css("display", "block");
    $("#address").html(delivery.address);
    $("#show-distance").html(delivery.distance + " Km");
    $("#show-duration").html(delivery.duration + " Mins");
    $("#show-price").html("€ " + delivery.price);
    $("#show-info").html("Info : " + delivery.information);
    $("#show-id").html("Pk : " + delivery.receipt_number)
}
```

Comment: Do you have an associated JavaScript file?  My guess is that your HTML and views are fine.

Comment: I have a script which outputs the information for each delivery on the map when clicked on, I have attached it above.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: I wasn't going to give up. Thanks. :)

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but your question, I found very useful, and so wanted to add my own answer, since after looking at your solution, I think there might be an issue.

Comment: I don't mind at all, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Keep id unique in html document**

The id in an HTML document must be unique within each page [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id):

> The id global attribute defines an identifier (ID) which must be
> unique in the whole document. Its purpose is to identify the element
> when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
> (with CSS).

What I think may have occurred is that since you have many cards in each page, all with the same id's, you were just getting the first one.  While your solution works, I think it might be better to give each id a unique value, which you can do simply by appending the `receipt_number`, or any unique field to the id names.  With this, you may not need the function `getTag`.  Here is what I mean:

**html**

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column h-100" style="padding-bottom: 50px">
    <div id="map"></div>
    {% if del %}
    {% for d in del %}
    <div class="card" id="delivery-popup{{ d.receipt_number }}">
        <div class="card-body p-2">
            <div class="details">
                <div class="p-2">
                    <strong id="address{{ d.receipt_number }}"></strong>
                    <div>
                        <strong id="show-info{{ d.receipt_number }}"></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong id="show-distance{{ d.receipt_number }}"></strong>
                        <strong id="show-duration{{ d.receipt_number }}"></strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <strong id="show-price{{ d.receipt_number }}"></strong>
                        <strong id="show-id{{ d.receipt_number }}"></strong>
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="accept">Accept</button>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ d.receipt_number }}" name="receipt_number">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    
  
                    {% if messages %}
                    {% for m in messages %}
                    {% if m.tags %}
                    <script>alert("{{ m }}")</script>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

**script**

```js
<script>
//Google map and using api to display deliveries on map and click event to show delivery details
function initMap() {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: { lat: 53.350140, lng: -6.266155 },
        zoom: 13,
    });

    fetch("{% url 'driver:available_deliveries' %}").then(response => response.json()).then(json => {
        console.log(json);

        for (let d = 0; d < json.deliveries.length; d++) {
            const delivery = json.deliveries[d];
            const position = { lat: delivery.delivery_address_latitude, lng: delivery.delivery_address_longitude };
            const show_on_map = new google.maps.Marker
                ({
                    position,
                    map,
                });

            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<small><strong>" + delivery.address + "<medium><br>€" + delivery.price
            }).open(map, show_on_map);

            show_on_map.addListener("click", () => {
                PopUpDelivery(delivery);
            })
        }
    })
}

function PopUpDelivery(delivery) {
    let pk = delivery.receipt_number
    $("#delivery-popup"+pk).css("display", "block");
    $("#address"+pk).html(delivery.address);
    $("#show-distance"+pk).html(delivery.distance + " Km");
    $("#show-duration"+pk).html(delivery.duration + " Mins");
    $("#show-price"+pk).html("€ " + delivery.price);
    $("#show-info"+pk).html("Info : " + delivery.information);
    $("#show-id"+pk).html("Pk : " + delivery.receipt_number)
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing this approach but it stills get the pk of the first card.

Comment: I saw my error and have edited my answer, @Shuaib.  I was using delivery.pk when I should have been using delivery.receipt_number.

Comment: {{ d.receipt_number }} is missing from id="delivery-popup", I got it to work but the only problem is that when I click on two or more deliveries, it shows them one after another instead of just displaying the clicked delivery only. Apart from that the accept button works prefectly. I'll just need to fix how the cards are being displayed one after another instead of just the clicked one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

Got the specific pk, when i click on a delivery it gets the right pk, code below if anyone has the same problem:

script

```
function PopUpDelivery(delivery) {
    $("#delivery-popup").css("display", "block");
    $("#address").html(delivery.address);
    $("#show-distance").html(delivery.distance + " Km");
    $("#show-duration").html(delivery.duration + " Mins");
    $("#show-price").html("€ " + delivery.price);
    $("#show-info").html("Info : " + delivery.information);
    $("#show-id").html("Pk : " + delivery.receipt_number);
    
    var input_tag = getTag('getpk');
    input_tag.value = delivery.receipt_number;
}
function getTag(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

html

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="accept">Accept</button>
                        <input type="hidden" id="getpk" value="" name="receipt_number">
```